# Java replace() problems

Tags: java, replace

I'm supposed to input a string, and replace all `and`, `to`, `you`, and `for` substrings with `&`, `2`, `U`, and `4`.

When I input the string `"and , and,and , to , to,to , you ,you , you, for ,for , for,a , a,e , e,i , i,o , o,u , u"`, it only outputs `and` when I print it.

```
public void simplify()
{
    System.out.println("Enter a string to simplify: ");
    String rope = in.next();
    System.out.println(simplifier(rope));
}
public String simplifier(String rope)
{

    rope = rope.replace(" and "," & ");
    rope = rope.replace(" and"," &");
    rope = rope.replace("and ","& ");
    rope = rope.replace(" to "," 2 ");
    rope = rope.replace(" to"," 2");
    rope = rope.replace("to ","2 ");
    rope = rope.replace(" you "," U ");
    rope = rope.replace("you ","U ");
    rope = rope.replace(" you"," U");
    rope = rope.replace(" for "," 4 ");
    rope = rope.replace("for ","4 ");
    rope = rope.replace(" for"," 4");
    rope = rope.replace("a ","");
    rope = rope.replace(" a","");
    rope = rope.replace("e ","");
    rope = rope.replace(" e","");
    rope = rope.replace("i ","");
    rope = rope.replace(" i","");
    rope = rope.replace(" o","");
    rope = rope.replace("o ","");
    rope = rope.replace("u ","");
    rope = rope.replace(" u","");
    System.out.print(rope);
    return rope;
}
```

Output:`and and`

It seems to cut off the returned string after the first space

I have no idea what is going on and why it is not working as it should.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "why it is not working as it should". What should it output?

Comment: Write the string down on paper. Manually replace everything. You'll see.. `replaceAll` replaces all the text from the first parameter with the text from the second parameter. Read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html for information.

Comment: You should note that  you are passing an argument to the method, but overwrite it inside the method with another String. Perhaps that's causing your confusion.

Comment: Your method (after closing the String literal in the first line), returns `& , &,& , 2 , 2,2 , U ,U , U, 4 ,4 , 4,,,,,,,,,,`

Comment: This string is supossed to return `& , &,& , 2 , 2,2 , U ,U , U, 4 ,4 , 4,,,,,,,,,,,`but the problem is that it returns `and` instead

Comment: @James - This code is *unreadable*. You have so many replaceAll statements. Very few people will actually try to understand what you are trying to do. Try editing the question and put only the code which is relevant and readable

Comment: @James you have to provide the code, which uses this method, because `simplifier()` returns exactly what you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I simplified your code and got the correct result:

```
    String rope = "and , and,and , to , to,to , you ,you , you, for ,for , for,a , a,e , e,i , i,o , o,u , u";

   // rope = rope.replaceAll(" ", "");
    rope = rope.replaceAll("and", "&");
    rope = rope.replaceAll("to", "2");
    rope = rope.replaceAll("you", "U");
    rope = rope.replaceAll("for", "4");
    rope = rope.replaceAll("a", "");
    rope = rope.replaceAll("e", "");
    rope = rope.replaceAll("i", "");
    rope = rope.replaceAll("o", "");
    rope = rope.replaceAll("u", "");
    System.out.println(rope);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, this worked for me. Thanks :)

Comment: @James glad it helped :) Please choose my answer or vote up, so I can work better to help others

Answer (score 0):

Replace the first `rope = rope.replace(" and "," & ");` with `rope = rope.replace("and "," & ");`

Now it should work. The problem was that the first "and" you were trying to replace was `and`, not `and`, which is why that was left and did not get replaced.

Also remove the second last line of `simplifier`, which is `System.out.print(rope);`. This is duplicate as you are already printing the result in the **calling method**.

---

UPDATE:
I see what you are trying to do here. Try this:

For each word that you want to replace, replace it only once. So for `and`, do:

```
rope.replace("and", "&");
```

For `to`, do:

```
rope.replace("to", "2");
```

**DO NOT** add any space between the words, it is not necessary. Doing `replace()` once will replace **ALL** occurrences of that word.

Comment: It Doesn't seem to work, when i inputted `and asdfasdf`, it still outputted `and and`

Comment: I tried your suggestion, and it still did not work. It seems as the return method stops when it meets a white space in the string, beause when i inputted `and hello`, it returned `&`, and when i inputted `  and hello`, `and` got returned