# Java - replace() method using values from arrays is changing the array values?

Tags: java, arrays, encryption, replace, replaceall

I'm doing something like

```
public static String[] list = {"a","b","c","d",}  //It gives me a NullPointeException if I didn't use static
public String encrypt(String a){
   a = a.replace(list[0],list[2]);
   a = a.replace(list[4],list[3]);
   return a;
}
```

and I have another method that just reverses it

```
public String decrypt(String a){
   a = a.replace(list[2],list[0]);
   a = a.replace(list[3],list[4]);
   return a;
}
```

Of course this is simplified, the real code I'm using uses the entire alphabet and some numbers. So here's my problem: If I input something like `123` into `encrypt()` and it outputs `ngV`  then I input `ngV` into decrypt()  it gives me like `1q3`. Only some of the letters are correctly switched and some aren't. Is there something with the `replace()` method using array values that I'm missing? I'm obviously new to Java.

Also I read [Java replace() problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33666602/java-replace-problems)  but `replaceAll()` didn't work out.

Comment: Strings are immutable, so you need to store the result of `a.replace(...);`

Comment: "If I input something like 123 into encrypt() and it outputs ngV" That's never going to happen.

Comment: I'm very sorry guys, I edited my code again. I had a = a.replace();
So Tunaki are you suggesting that I store the result of a.replace.
However, the problem is still the same, Do you want a video of me demonstrating it?

Comment: @MichaelChen Use the "@" before the user's name to send him a notification.

Comment: Please provide a full example. The code posted above does not work: The array cannot be assigned like that and ``list[4]`` does not exist. Break down the problem into your own small sample program and post it here.

Comment: Put some `System.out.println(a)` after each replace (or use a debugger).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your question is "why is chaining `.replace` acting oddly" and the array is not changing. You can prove that replace does not change the array quite easily:

```
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(list));
    encrypt("abc");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(list));
```

So what is going on with your code? Each time you replace a letter you end up with a new string, that again you replace letters on. I don't have your full source code so I'll show with a real simple version:

```
a = a.replace("a", "b");
a = a.replace("b", "c");
a = a.replace("c", "d");
```

For "abc" is.... 'ddd'.

The answer to this is to look at each letter at a time and change it. Loop through the string and create a new one.