# Java .replace() seems to modify an array

Tags: java, replace, replaceall

I'm doing something like

```
public static String[] list = {"a","b","c","d",}  //It gives me a NullPointeException if I didn't use static
public String encrypt(String a){
   a = a.replace(list[0],list[2]);
   a = a.replace(list[4],list[3]);
   return a;
}
```

and I have another method that just reverses it

```
public String decrypt(String a){
   a = a.replace(list[2],list[0]);
   a = a.replace(list[3],list[4]);
   return a;
}
```

Of course this is simplified, the real code I'm using uses the entire alphabet and some numbers. So here's my problem: If I input something like `123` into `encrypt()` and it outputs `ngV`  then I input `ngV` into decrypt()  it gives me like `1q3`. Only some of the letters are correctly switched and some aren't. Is there something with the `replace()` method using array values that I'm missing? I'm obviously new to Java.

Also I read [Java replace() problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33666602/java-replace-problems)  but `replaceAll()` didn't work out.

Earlier, a moderator called Tunaki told me it was a duplicate, but I didn't find any other problems on stackoverflow that addressed this issue. If you guys can't figure out what the problem is from my sample above, I can post the actual code I have (it's the same thing, except the whole alphabet).

Comment: Please edit your previous question and try to explain why it's not a duplicate to get it reopened.

Comment: @Michael Chen Tunaki is not a moderator.

Comment: And please give example input/output that actually shows the problem behavior with the code you posted.

Comment: Also please note that you totally changed your original question. You *didn't* assign the result returned by `replace`; which is why your question was marked as duplicate.

Comment: I didn't assign the result returned by replace? I thought it always returned a string like http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_replace.htm.

Comment: Actually, I just figured out what my problem is, so I have a humongous list of .replace() but I didn't realize that...for example a.replace(b,c) and then later there would be a a.replace(c,d). I know how to fix this part. Thanks anyways